# Fill missing array data with 0 on missing dates

Tags: javascript, dataset

I have the following MySQL query that groups my data by date and status columns and gives me a dataset in the following way:

```
{date: '2020-04-20', status: 'Active', total: 4},
{date: '2020-04-20', status: 'Paid', total: 6},
{date: '2020-04-20', status: 'Waiting', total: 7},
{date: '2020-04-20', status: 'New', total: 4},
{date: '2020-04-21', status: 'Active', total: 7},
{date: '2020-04-21', status: 'Paid', total: 4}
```

My goal is to create a line chart where the x-axis will be the different dates, statuses that do not have any data on the given day are just assigned a 0.

I am trying to create the following arrays:

X-axis: `'2020-04-20', '2020-04-21'`
Y-axis: `Active, Wait, Paid, New`

I can create the previous arrays successfully using the ...set function however I've been struggling to assign the value 0 when a date is not present.

Solving this problem would result in the following datasets

```
Wating = [7, 0] New = [4, 0] Active = [4,7] Paid = [6,4]
```

I don't know If this array-creating approach is the correct one due to the possibility of there being 1 or 25 different statuses.

Perhaps iterating on the object using the statuses and assigning 0 where the date column is not present? I'm completely lost here.

I appreciate any help.

Also, modifying the query is out of the question I would like to do this with js.